# How to install Solana on Windows?

Tags: solana

I ran:

`curl https://release.solana.com/v1.8.3/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs`

In my Windows command prompt and it showed up like this:
[image: Command Prompt]

It seemed like it installed - so then I did `solana --version` and this is what happened:

`'solana' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I ran `solana --version` in Powershell, Git Bash, VS Code Terminal, and Command Prompt and it gives the same output.

How do I install Solana?

Thank you!

Comment: take a look at this link for enabling wsl and installing solana on Linux subsystem: https://docs.figment.io/network-documentation/extra-guides/solana-setup-for-windows

Comment: You just downloaded exe but installation is pending. Please execute below command to install:
C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.15.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try :

More details on:https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

step1:

```
curl https://release.solana.com/v1.8.3/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows- 
msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs
```

step2:

```
C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.8.3
```

Note: you have to open a command prompt as administrator

Comment: When I ran step one: https://ibb.co/7WcWr4f - do you think the issue is with curl? Do I need to install it - or is it always installed on the computer? Or do I need to install rust?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) as an Administrator and it will work.

Comment: Tried doing that just now: https://ibb.co/KxhzmyD

Comment: you tried the step-1 command separately run all at once.

Comment: I ran the whole `curl https://release.solana.com/v1.8.3/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows- 
msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs` and for some reason, it separates it - is it because of the `C:\` part?

Comment: I tried the same on my Windows 10 PC and it's working.

Comment: Do I need to install Rust (or Curl) you think?

Comment: no, I don't think so if you have windows 10 it will work or see the above-attached documentation.

Comment: I've already read the Solana and Metaplex docs before asking this question - and they didn't say anything about this problem, so I'm guessing it's my computer...? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: yeah, it might be but in my case, it's working without doing any... which window you are using?

Comment: I'm using Command Prompt - if that's what you mean. If you mean the PC company thing, it's Lenovo

Comment: which window you are using? window 8 ,window 10 or 11?

Comment: **Edition:** Windows 10 Home

Comment: well, then clear all the cache and try it must work.

Comment: Where do I clean my cache sorry? In my browser? Sorry :(

Comment: the cache of the computer.

Comment: Cleaned computer cache, went back in terminal: https://ibb.co/TbHgwmx

Comment: Thank you Gretal! I did this on Git Bash and it works!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I tried a lot of things, git bash, cmd, everything were in administrator, however I couldn't.

But I got it, I tried with another versions (v1.8.5 , v1.9.5, v1.10.5)

`curl https://release.solana.com/v1.9.5/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-  msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs`

**My problem was solve when I tried with (v1.9.5)**

Answer (score 0):

> C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.8.6

```
Install is up to date. 1.8.6 is the latest compatible release

The HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment/PATH registry key has been modified to include:
  C:\Users\Krogf\.local\share\solana\install\active_release\bin

Future applications will automatically have the correct environment, but you may need to restart your current shell.

Press the Enter key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure you are running as admin I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You did step 1 of 2 to install Solana - right now you have the directory of files copied,

Run `C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.8.3` to actually install. Then make sure that either PATH is auto-updated or copy the generated PATH and update it manually.

CLOSE the CMD right after and relaunch. THEN try `Solana --version`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having issues with the above curl answer I had to add the --ssl-no-revoke for it to ignore SSL cert issues and download:

`curl https://release.solana.com/v1.9.16/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs --ssl-no-revoke`